# undefined:1 error when trying to access parsed JSON value in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, https

I'm trying to make a very basic news web application to learn how to use APIs. The API that I'm using is https://newsapi.org/ .

[This is the JSON object that I'm trying to console.log and the "undefined:1" error message that I'm receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Pa3.png)

This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Sample text");

  const url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=_______________________';

  https.get(url, function(response) {

    response.on("data", function(data) {
      const newsData = JSON.parse(data);
      const results = newsData.totalResults;
      console.log(results);
    });
  });

});

app.listen("3000", function(req, res) {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

I took out my API key so that people on StackOverflow can't access my account on the news API, but the API key is in my code. **As seen in the link above, I want to console.log the "totalResults" key-value pair in the JSON object so that "38" appears in the console, but instead I'm receiving "undefined:1".**

How would I change my code so that I don't get the "undefined:1" error and that I can display any of the JSON values?

Comment: Can you console.log data directly before parsing it and see are you getting anything in response

Comment: I get something that looks like hexadecimal: <Buffer 7b 22 73... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting the response in chunks. The `data` event is fired when a chunk is received, but a separate `end` event needs to be used to handle getting the last of the data.

Instead of the `data` event handler treating `data` as the entire response, it should append `data` to a string. Then you should add an `end` handler that attempts to do the `JSON.parse`.

There's [a good example in the NodeJS docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback) that addresses your use case.

---

As an aside, you may want to look into using [the `request` library](https://github.com/request/request), which simplifies this process. I use it since I don't like messing with the event handlers like this in the vanilla Node request API.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify: I understand that networks send data over in chunks/packets. Are you saying that the event handler response.on("data", ___) is called when it receives the very first chunk and then stops? Thus, to fix this problem, I should have the chunks be added to a string, and then use response.on("end", ___) to parse the JSON?

Comment: I followed the NodeJS docs and it solved my issue! Thank you :)